# can not pass groovy parameter value to soapUI request xml

Tags: groovy, soapui

Want to pass bankaTalimatNo parameter to following request from groovy script. 
I created a test case level property called bankaTalimatiNo.

Inside the groovy script i iterate an array to set values property values correcty but the generated request does not change in parallel with the property value.

What should be the correct XML expression to achieve this?
thanks in advance

> ```
>    <soapenv:Header/>
>    <soapenv:Body>
>       <wso:kurumOdemesiSorgulaRequest>
>          <wso:bankaTalimatiNo>${Properties#bankaTalimatiNo}</wso:bankaTalimatiNo>
>       </wso:kurumOdemesiSorgulaRequest>
>    </soapenv:Body>
> </soapenv:Envelope>
> ```

and the groovy script is as follows

```
project = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject().getWorkspace().getProjectByName("maliye")
testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite 1");
testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName("TestCase 1");
testStep=testCase.testSteps["SOAP Request1"]

 File file = new File("C:/temp/test.txt")
      file.write "This is the first line\n"

def  String[] talimatNoArray = [
"3"


];

talimatNoArray.eachWithIndex{talimatNo, i->

 testCase.setPropertyValue("bankaTalimatiNo"  , "${talimatNo}");



    log.info "aaa"+ testCase.getPropertyValue("bankaTalimatiNo");
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
    context.bankaTalimatiNo=testStep.getPropertyValue("bankaTalimatiNo");
    def responseHolder=testStep.getPropertyValue("response");



    //Check if the response is not empty
    assert responseHolder, 'Response is empty or null'


}
```

Generated request is always the same , the expression is never evaluated

```
>  <soapenv:Envelope
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:wso="http://maliye.yte.bilgem.tubitak.gov.tr/odeme/kurumodemesi/server/wso">
> <soapenv:Header/>    <soapenv:Body>
>       <wso:kurumOdemesiSorgulaRequest>
>          <wso:bankaTalimatiNo>${bankaTalimatiNo}</wso:bankaTalimatiNo>
>       </wso:kurumOdemesiSorgulaRequest>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the request, change from:

```
<wso:bankaTalimatiNo>${Properties#bankaTalimatiNo}</wso:bankaTalimatiNo>
```

To:

```
<wso:bankaTalimatiNo>${#TestCase#bankaTalimatiNo}</wso:bankaTalimatiNo>
```

Comment: @desperado06, glad it helped. Appreciated if you can upvote the helpful answer.